# post values from multiselect2side after new value selected

Tags: jquery, select, jquery-plugins

i have two select input on form ( one is main selection - "curentOpt", second one is multiple selection - "selection_cats") 
on second one i use multiselect2side jquery plugin. This setup is used for map selection_cats to currentOpt.

My idea is that when selection_cats is changed ( selected option is added ) post via ajax new array of currently selected values

My html

```
<select name="curentOpt" id="category">
    <option value="1" > Option 1 </option>
    <option value="2" > Option 2 </option>
    <option value="3" > Option 3 </option>
    <option value="4" > Option 4 </option>
    <option value="5" > Option 5 </option>
    <option value="6" > Option 6 </option>
</select>   
<br/><br/><br/>
<select name="CatsSelection" multiple="multiple" id="selection_cats" style="width: 200px" size="20">
    <option value="100" >Selection 11 </option>
    <option value="101" >Selection 12 </option>
    <option value="102" >Selection 13 </option>
    <option value="103" >Selection 14 </option>
    <option value="104" >Selection 15 </option>
    <option value="105" >Selection 16 </option>
    <option value="106" >Selection 17 </option>
    <option value="107" >Selection 18 </option>
    <option value="300" >Selection 19 </option>
    <option value="301" >Selection 20 </option>
    <option value="302" >Selection 21 </option>
    <option value="303" >Selection 22 </option>
</select>
```

And my JS

```
// default options for multiselect2side
var defaultOpt = {
    selectedPosition: 'left',
    moveOptions: false,
    labelsx: '',
    labeldx: '',
    autoSort: true,
    autoSortAvailable: true
};


$('#selection_cats').multiselect2side(defaultOpt);

$('#selection_cats').change(function(){
    alert('changed');

});
```

my code is on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kmiddler/LCC2z/12/

i try to use .change() on #selection_cats and #CatsSelectionms2side__sx ( this was created after multiselect2side is applied to #selection_cats.

but both doesn't work, i can't get values from #selection_cats after i change selected values ( add or delete some )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use $(document).on("change",fn);, it should work

```
                          $(document).on("change",function(){
                             $('#selection_cats').on("change",function(){
                               alert('changed');
                             });

                           });
```

[Your Updated Fiddle Working](http://jsfiddle.net/LCC2z/13/)

Comment: but for some reason multiselect2side is lost, how ever this work but i need this in multiselect2side

Comment: i give you accepted for "normal" multiple select without multiselect2side plugin